# Get more than million rows from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

In past I got `System.OutOfMemoryException` during loading more than a million rows into a `DataTable` from a SQL Server database. Is it true that instead of filling `DataTable`, it is much faster e.g to load it somehow to `CSV` or any other format besides? Please of your advice, eventually with given propose / example.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. What is the end destination of all your data? Analysis? another data store? you need to be more specific. Otherwise all we can tell you is to buy more RAM maybe?

Comment: `DataTable`s are obsolete since years ago, so avoid those whenever possible. Besides, that means that you'll hold a whole copy of the dataset in memory, so it's better to use the `SqlDataReader` directly and send the data somewhere else. Of course, selecting millons of records at once has its own series of problems, so try to limit that if possible.

Comment: Batch process rows from Database table. That can be an option.

Comment: @CodeMonkey at the end the destination will be datagridview which i already prepared with virtualmode. SO i need to somehow download records from database (for sure not datatable) and then use in datagridview

Comment: @Alejandro unfortunetly i have to download million of records for analystic purposes, the destination is datagridview which i configured in virtualmode, so somehow i need to avoid dwonloading records to Datatable, but somewhere else and then use in datagridview, what you propose csv file maybe?

Comment: @Arie A datagrid with a millon of records is simply unusable for any purpose, virtualization or not, there is no way a user can see all of them. You may try implementing paging or virtual loading instead, or some kind of search to restrict how many rows are displayed instead.

Comment: @Alejandro i solve it loading milion of records into csv and then used datagridview virtual mode

Comment: @Arie depending on what your doing you could look into pagination if your SQL table is able to support it. You can implement this hidden or visible to the user. With actual pages or infinity scroll. If this is a desktop app or web app you need to determine your needs and those of your users.Whats the required minimum RAM for a good user experience. Putting this into a CSV file don't really solve anything if your data grows, and your stil just reading the entire CSV file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how you might use the data, you could pull all the data using a `SqlDataReader` and than write that to a SQLite database file.  This essentially gives you a local cached version of the million rows that you can query as if it were stored in the database, but doesn't take up memory since it's written to a local file (and provides in-memory cache if needed).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: My target is to use that data in datagridview - i already configured it in virtualmode. So what you propose is to load data from sql server to local sqllite file using SqlDataReader and then when grid neds specific rows just ask sqllite by quering it?

Comment: Additional question what about CSV? If i would the same as written above but instead of sqllite read data from sql server using sqldatareader to csv and then use that csv for datagridview?

Comment: Honestly, as others have mentioned, you really do need to page the results.  Storing in Sqlite was just an alternative to CSV because it is essentially a file that can be used like a database in cases where your roundtrips to a regular SQL server would otherwise be too slow but it very flexible because you wouldn't have to write an implementation of a datatable over the top of it.

Comment: I see, therefore whatever i choose either sqllite, csv, xml whatever then those are much more better than datatable right?

Comment: If you are binding to a grid, I'd consider ditching the datatable and just use straight poco class of the data and bind to that.  If you really need the tracking capabilities of a datatable, I'd go the EF core route, especially in this case, where you may encounter some performance issues.   If you run into trouble, you could change out the EF core data provider with one that may work better for you without changing any of your code down the road (sql for sqlite, etc).                                                                            https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/